# How can I print Object's value in PHP which is fetched row from SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I have tried to print values of my PHP object '$mon' which is having average of all months.....

and My code for data fetch is as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT b_year, sum(m1) as m1, sum(m2) as m2, sum(m3) as m3, sum(m4) as m4, sum(m5) as m5, sum(m6) as m6, sum(m7) as m7, sum(m8) as m8, sum(m9) as m9, sum(m10) as m10, sum(m11) as m11, sum(m12) as m12  
            from s_budgets as b INNER JOIN users as u on b.u_id = u.id WHERE b_year=YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
GROUP BY b_year " );
$mon=mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

and my code for Displaying those values are as below....

```
 <?php echo $mon->m4;?>,
 <?php echo $mon->m5;?>,
 <?php echo $mon->m6;?>,
```

how can I print the object '$mon' with its several properties?

Comment: If it is for testing purpose just use print_r($mon) or you need to loop and do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$mon isn't an object because mysql_fetch_array fetches an array from a MySQL resource. You'll have to access your array like so:

```
<?php echo $mon['m4']; ?>,
<?php echo $mon['m5']; ?>,
<?php echo $mon['m6']; ?>,
```

You'll need to use [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) if you're wanting an object.

Answer (score 2):

This `$mon=mysql_fetch_array($result) fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both`..

```
echo $mon['m4'];
```

If you want result as object, then use following way

```
$mon = mysql_fetch_object($result)
$mon->m4
```

> Please start to use Mysqli or PDO for new development.

Answer (score 2):

You need to used mysql_fetch_object() rather than mysql_fetch_array() in order to access the data in an object format.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for debugging purposes, a simple

```
var_dump($mon);
```

gives you all properties of `$mon`.

Otherwise try iterating over the result array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     echo $row['m4']; // etc.
}
```

Comment: you can also use "print_r", which is a great alternative for "var_dump"